# Multilingual website: one table or multi-tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, multilingual

I'm building a multilingual website in PHP.

At first I was considering to use JSON file with a structure like

```
{
  "TEXT_CODE": {
     "LANG_CODE": "TEXT",
     "LANG_CODE": "TEXT"
   }
}
```

But then, since the texts could be a lot, I opted for a database solution that should be more handable and readable.

---

Assuming we have 200 texts and 5 languages, which is the best option in terms of database design mixed with performances?

### Solution 1

A single table `texts_multilingual` with `200 * 5 = 1000` rows to search among at each page request.

### Solution 2

One table per each language `texts_en`, `texts_it`, etc. so that each research would search only among 200 rows for the *text code*.

---

I guess solution #2 is the best way in terms of performances but I would like to know the opinion of more expert developers and how they would handle it.

Comment: You won't notice any performance difference at all between 200 vs 1000 rows. Just make sure you index your data properly and your set.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sure, mine was just an example. I asked since this project could scale quite much and I'd like to have a proper structure since the beginning

Comment: Sure, but we're talking major amounts of data before you're actually notice any difference, and then, you will probably need to cluster your db anyway.

Comment: Despite I favouring solution one I want to throw a third way into the discussion: A table consisting of the fields "Text_Id", "Text_en", "Text_it", "Text_de" etc.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I got what you mean and you're totally right

Comment: @user5329483 That's not a good idea. If you add a new language, you will need to add a new column and re-index the complete table. If you need to alter your tables just to add a new language, you need to rethink your design.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yeah, I agree. I saw this at my company's software and it is annoying having a huge 2D table on the screen for editing. However missing translations cold be easier detected than the linear solution.

Comment: @user5329483 That's easily found if you have a `textid` as the answer suggests. Simply get the distinct `textid` and then check the languages. You need to think about what's the most common usage is (like simply fetching the data) and design after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is the better solution.  Why?

First, you have only one table and you can optimize the table for your queries, using indexes and partitioning.

Second, you can add a new language quite easily.  There is no new table to add.

Third, you can readily see what languages you have in the table and whether you have translations for all texts in all languages.

For performance, you simply want an index on the table . . . `texts_multilingual(language, textid, text)`.  In fact, you might consider making this a primary key.  Personally, I prefer having an auto-incremented primary key.  But because this table is rarely updated, used in one specific way, and unlikely to have foreign key relationships, having a composite primary key is also reasonable.

Comment: Your answer, joined with @Magnus Eriksson's consideration, persuaded me that the first solution is the best way. Also your consideration upon a composite primary key is great, thanks Gordon